# Passing property to LWC component

Tags: api, lightning-web-components

Trying to pass a default value to an @api decorated property, somehow I get undefined variable, here is my code
meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="mroConsumptionTable">
    <apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage">
            <property
                    name="type"
                    label="Per slot array"
                    type="String"
                    default="Single Rate"
                    required="true"
            />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

.js

```
 @api set type(value){
        console.log('in set type');
        console.log(value);
        this._type = value;
        this.generateData();
    }
    get type(){
        return this._type;
    }
```

If you don't have a solution for this exact code, at least do share a working example of passing a property to a component

Comment: I did similar work. I used LWC with the flow and in that, I used these parameters https://newstechnologystuff.com/2019/10/20/lightning-web-components-in-lightning-flow/

Comment: @TusharSharma the website is unreachable

Comment: I just tested and it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do something similar with the following, and I know this works. In the meta:

```
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
        <property name="definitionName" label="Definition Name" type="String" required="true" datasource="apex://ScheduleDefinitionPickList"/>
        <property name="minimumHeight" label="Minimum Height" type="String" default="30em" required="false"/>
    </targetConfig>
```

In the component:

```
/**
 * The configured minimum height get.
 *
 * @return {string}
 */
@api get minimumHeight() {
    return this._minimumHeight;
}

set minimumHeight(value) {
    this._minimumHeight = value;
    this.state.rootStyle = value ? `min-height: ${value};` : '';
}
```

The only difference I can see is actually around where the @api is put when having get/set functions. We put it on the get, not on the set (the @api in this case can only go on one of the functions and we put it on the get).

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work in my case, I need this component to be able to accept data from outer component that's why I need a setter, I wanted to use this default target property just for testing but it looks like it's easier to create another component for this purpose

Comment: I think what phil is saying is the @api decorator just needs to be put on the get, but it will be applicable on both the get and set.