# calling wire method on user selection in js-meta.xml file

Tags: lightning-web-components

[image]I am trying to access the value of property Name "relatedObjects" selected by user in js-meta.xml file as below and want to proceed this value in next apex controller for property name "fieldName"

```
<targetConfigs>
<targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage"> 
<property name="relatedObjects" type="String" label="Related Objects" datasource="apex://FetchLookupRelationship" required="true" requiredMessage="Please select a value." value="{!relatedObjectsValue}" />
<property name="fieldName" type="String" label="Field Name" description="Enter the field name" datasource="apex://FetchTextFields"/>
</targetConfig>  
</targetConfigs>
```

Javscript code

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getobjectName from '@salesforce/apex/getRelatedObjectValue.getobjectName';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class RelatedList extends LightningElement {
    @api objectApiName;
    @api fieldName;
    
    @api recordId;
    @api strTitle;

    _relatedObjectsValue;

    @wire(getobjectName, { relatedObjects: '$_relatedObjectsValue' })
    records({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('Data:', data);
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    }

    @api
    get relatedObjectsValue() {
        console.log('data------------>',this._relatedObjectsValue);
        return this._relatedObjectsValue;
    }

    set relatedObjectsValue(value) {
        this._relatedObjectsValue = value;
        refreshApex(this.records);
    }

    @api
    get relatedObjects() {
        console.log('data------------>',this.relatedObjectsValue);
        return this.relatedObjectsValue;
    }

    set relatedObjects(value) {
        this.relatedObjectsValue = value;
    }
}
```

it works only at the time of loading but when i set the value for RelatedObjects, it does not call the apex controller.
I am thankful in advance.

[image]

Comment: This is not possible ... as the name says its a meta file  you do not make those configurations dynamic ... same with your entries in the page editor.

Don't be over creative for your own good

Comment: Hi Arihant, Thanks for your kind response. if we could populated values in object name and related objects, then why can't we get the value of related objects and populate the value in Field Name based on related objects.

Answer (score 0):

Because the preview runs on load... like a static script .. when you embed it, it executes and you get the objects list, but when you select the object it no longer runs as dynamic exection based on changes in meta xml parameters is just not how the LWC structure works.

Hard code an object in code and instead of object, onload try the field one you will find it working, but expecting something to run on selection is not how its supposed to be

Comment: I added one more photo. it shows that response gives this value but i can't access this in js-code.

Comment: you get the selection value ...but the call for fieldnames is not happening... 
'dynamic exection based on changes in meta xml parameters doesn't work' do not try to make this work if this goes for a salesforce review I have no idea how this will pan out....
Why don't you have a discussion with SF support if this approach should be followed or not ?

Comment: Please read this. they are getting value from meta file. 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292148/passing-property-to-lwc-component